# How to remove ssh keys?

Tags: server, ssh

Learning how to use public keys with ssh server

following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial by DigitalOcean

ssh server : kali VM

ssh client : Ubuntu VM

Using an Ubuntu VM I generated a couple of ssh keys but I only need one to use since the others are somewhat duplicates but have a different password

running this command  `ssh-copy-id kali@192.168.1.10`

returns

```
Number of key(s) added: 4

Now try logging into the machine, with: "ssh 'kali@192.168.1.10'"
and check to make sure that only the key(s) you wanted were added.
```

How do you remove the keys to be added and stick to the only key generated when running `ssh-keygen`

I tried to delete the keys by running this command  `sudo rm -rf /home/kali/.ssh`

but every time I try to copy the newly generated key I get 4 keys on the kali VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are copying 4 keys to your server.

This is taken from the online documentation located at
https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/copy-id

**-i** Specifies the identity file that is to be copied (default is ~/.ssh/id_rsa). **If this option is not provided, this adds all keys listed by ssh-add -L**. Note: it can be multiple keys and adding extra authorized keys can easily happen accidentally! If ssh-add -L returns no keys, then the most recently modified key matching ~/.ssh/id*.pub, excluding those matching ~/.ssh/*-cert.pub, will be used.

**Update** from the comments:

If you which to remove a certain key just use:

> $ rm  .ssh/id_target_key*

One of the backup options can be:

> $ mv .ssh/id_target_key      id_target_key.bak

Remember that there are always 2 keys. One private and one public. The latter has the extension .pub

Where to locate these keyfiles?
**On the server** open **/etc/ssh/sshd_config** and look for

> AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys

This file can be edited in order to remove your key manually, there might be other users keys installed.

**On the client** open **/etc/ssh/ssh_config** and look for an alternative path from there. (Mine is all commented out so ~/.ssh is the default location) ~/ is a relative path which changes per user. Executing the ssh command set with **sudo** will result in a different path: **/root**.

Comment: I want to remove the 4 keys and create a new one and copy it without the `-i` options if possible

Comment: Do you have multiple keys located in your Ubuntu VM? ( $ ls .ssh/ )

Comment: yes and i wish to remove them all

Comment: typing `cd .ssh/` shows only one key but when i create a new key i the number of ssh keys increases by one up to 6 now is there any other folder ?

Comment: Do you type sudo perhaps? Then it gets added in the root home folder. Also delete the keys at the server side.

Comment: after rebooting the client i was left with one key for some reason it didn't refresh or didn't realize that i deleted the keys

Comment: @SecTeam AFAIK none of the above removes the *public keys* from the remote host's `authorized_keys` file - which is what you really should care about from a security POV.

Comment: Good point, although Sec Team removed the whole folder on the server side. Which is, off course, a bit like shooting with a cannon to a mosquito.